# How to fix Feb 5, 2020 No task bar search results bug in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, search, taskbar

There is a new issue in Windows that is preventing mostly any use of the START button with you keyboard. Did anyone figure out a fix yet?

[This is the official statement I saw](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-fix-taskbar-search-not-working-windows-10)

> Editor's note from February 5, 2020: Some Windows 10 users appear to be experiencing an issue with task bar search, in which the box appears blank and does not display search results. We're currently investigating the issue and will update this post accordingly with any new fixes we may find.

Things that I tried and did not work for my machine:

1. Restart the Windows Search service from the task manager.
2. Reindexing - Rebuilding indices from Control Panel -> Indexing Options -> Advance

One thing that works some of the time is to type what I want into the address bar inside File Explorer.

Comment: [The issue you describe is not a known issue.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1903) Have you reported the issue to Microsoft through the Feedback application?  Your official statement is from an editor not Microsoft by the way[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1522905/windows-10-search-not-loading-showing-blank-window/1522923#1522923).  In order to help you resolve this problem, you cannot refer to just the issue, you must provide enough information about the issue.  None of my machines are affected by this issue.

Comment: If the duplicate solves this problem, you should flag this question as a duplicate, instead of a temporary comment indicating the answer to the duplicate is a solution to this problem.