# Why does a black opaque box cover the search window?

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

It happens ever so often. Sometimes it covers the entire thing, sometimes part of it. My system is up-to-date. It disappears when I click on it, but if I click anything else in the search window, it comes back.

[Here's a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDMSA.png)

Comment: Before you perform time consuming SFC or DISM scans I highly encourage you to read the previous [answers](https://superuser.com/questions/1522905/windows-10-search-not-loading-showing-blank-window/1523134#1523134) that described a similar problem.  It was reported that a simply reboot would solve the problem.  If a reboot does not solve the problem, verify you are not using a proxy, that is blocking the necessary connections to Microsoft.  If you are using a proxy then disabling the Bing search is the appropriate solution.

Comment: @Ramhound I have rebooted _many_ times, ran `sfc /scannow` _and_ DISM, along with `chkdsk /f`

Comment: How about block the Bing search results since it appears your not running Windows 10 version 2004

Comment: @Ramhound what do you mean by disabling the Bing search?

Comment: Have you read the answers to the other question?  Specifically the answer that received more than 120 upvotes?

Comment: Well the answer with 123 upvotes explains in explicit detail how to disable Bing search SearchUI.exe functionality

Comment: @Ramhound but I want Bing

Comment: It does not appear Bing search is currently working.  What we are attempting to do is to see if Bing search is actually the problem.  If the solution I am pointing to you, actually does resolve the problem, then you have a communication problem.  You can reinstall Windows all you want but if you don't identify the network problem those reinstall/resets won't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That was a problem Microsoft had some months ago (pre-lockdown) and long fixed, so there is probably something about your system.

Try the following:

Start by trying DISM and SFC.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run in order:

dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
SFC /SCANNOW
Restart when done and test WinVer again.

If the DISM repair does not fix the issue, run a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.

Windows 10 Repair Install

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

The test the Search Window again.

Comment: I've run both DISM and SFC, along with CHKDSK.

Comment: Now try the Repair Install to fix the system.

Comment: Will I lose any data?

Comment: In a standard Repair Install (starting with Keep Everything) no, you will not lose data.

Comment: About how long does it take?

Comment: Download time about 1/2 hour ( could be less). Rebuild time: 90 minutes thereabouts.  You can use the machine for the download time and the repair preparation time.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me what `rebuild` is?

Comment: It re-creates your system, keeps data, and puts the old system in windows.old in case it is needed.

Comment: That should work and fix the search box.